Find first value alongside grouping and aggregation - BigQuery
I have some data that includes a series of events that map back to a specific ID, with a value associated with them:

What I want to create is a table that groups by ID, and includes two columns: the total amount, and the original amount.

More specifically I want to do this in a single query. I know that I can use, say, FIRST_VALUE() to partition by id, order by date and then select the original amount. The issue is that because you can't aggregate the results of analytic functions, I can't do that in the same query in which I sum the total amount and group by ID.
(The reason for doing it in a single query is to do with how this will be built that becomes very use-case specific.)
Are there any workarounds I can use to achieve the above results table without needing a multi-level query?

I’m not sure I fully understand the constraints here. I don’t think it can be done without a sub query. Without knowing why that is a limitation I can only speculate. If you wrap this logic into a table function then you can query that as if it were a simple select from.

This answer is for SQL Server, but you should be able to get the idea.
Just aggregate to get your total amount, as well as find the earliest date, for each id. Then join back to the underlying table to get the amount associated with that id and earliest date.
The only caveat is it won't work if the id and date field are not unique in the underlying table...
SELECT agginp.id
    , agginp.total_amount
    , inp.amount AS first_amount
FROM InputData inp
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MIN([date]) AS min_date
        , SUM(amount) AS total_amount
        , id
    FROM InputData
    GROUP BY id
    ) agginp
    on inp.ID = agginp.ID
        AND inp.[date] = agginp.min_date;

Try it yourself: db<>fiddle
